# Laravel 5 Routing to CSS folder issue

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, routes

I have the following route which loads the page but the `css` of the page doesn't loads.

```
Route::get('admins', function () {
        return view('admins/index');
});
```

In the contrast the following route loads the same page but here I added `index` and the page loads correctly. but I also adds `index` with `admins` in the browser address bar.

```
Route::get('admins/index', function () {
        return view('admins/index');
});
```

I am calling `css` files in the views like:

```
<link href="../assets/css/animate.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
```

I searched for the solutions but didn't got anything.

Comment: How do you call the css? And where is it located? Any error on developer console log?

Comment: If that's how you're referring it. You should put your css folder in `public/css` instead of `resources/assets`. And set the href to `css/animate.min.css`.

Comment: The assets folder is already in the public folder.

Comment: Post your project structure including `admins/index` and `assets`. Or you can just `View Page Source` and click the link whether it redirects you properly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**For Laravel 4 & 5:**

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ URL::asset('assets/css/animate.min.css') }}">
```

**URL::asset** will link to your `project/public/ folder`, so chuck your scripts in there.

**Note:** You'll need to be using blade templates to use this. All Blade templates should use the .blade.php extension.

Comment: but the `css` files are working when i access `poject/public/admins/index` but does not works when i access `poject/public/admins`. The `index` page loads but the `css` files does not loads.

Comment: what you see in the css link when you view the page source while accessing project/public/admins ?

Comment: `<link href="../assets/plugins/jquery-ui/themes/base/minified/jquery-ui.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />`

Comment: and in poject/public/admins/index ??

Comment: ok i changed the path and the `poject/public/admins` works fine but now the `poject/public/admins/index` is not working and the `css` is not loading.

Comment: Check your web inspector and see what the URL is that it is trying to find the CSS file. Look at the network tab it will show you what it is trying to load

Comment: what you see in the css link in poject/admins/index when you view the source ?

Comment: My pleasure :) Happy Coding :)

Answer (score 1):

i am using code like below for css and js :

`<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('/') }}css/menu-style.css">`

And css directory is in my "project/public" directory.